# List of all transactions of a *specific* ERC20 token for a given wallet address using the alchemy-sdk?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, etherscan, transfer, alchemy

For example, if I want to see all of the USDC transactions related to my wallet address, how can I fetch all of those transactions?

USDC contract address: [0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48)

My wallet address: `0xF5FFF32CF83A1A614e15F25Ce55B0c0A6b5F8F2c`

I took a look at the [Etherscan Transactions API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/stats), but it looks like you need to know a `txn hash` ahead of time and it only fetches the data about that one transaction.

I am now specifically curious about how to use the **[alchemy-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alchemy-sdk)** to accomplish this task, as I am using that library across my project.

How do I list all txns of a specific ERC20 token for a given wallet address?

Answer (score 0):

Developer Advocate at Alchemy here :)

You can do this with the `getAssetTransfers` endpoint from the [Alchemy Transfers API](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-getassettransfers), which the [Alchemy SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alchemy-sdk) has support for.

For example, in javascript:

```js
// Setup: npm install alchemy-sdk
const alchemySdk = require("alchemy-sdk");
const Alchemy = alchemySdk.Alchemy;
const Network = alchemySdk.Network;

(async function main() {
  // Configure the Alchemy SDK instance with an https://www.alchemy.com API key.
  const config = {
    apiKey: "your api key",
    network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
  };
  const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

  // Define the address and ERC20 token contract I care about.
  const USDCaddress = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
  const thatguyintech = "thatguyintech.eth";

  // Fetch transactions going into the desired address.
  const usdcTransfersToAlbert = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
    toAddress: thatguyintech,
    contractAddresses: [USDCaddress],
    category: ["erc20"],
  });

  console.log("transfers to me: ", usdcTransfersToAlbert);

  // Fetch transactions leaving from the desired address.
  const usdcTransfersFromAlbert = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
    fromAddress: thatguyintech,
    contractAddresses: [USDCaddress],
    category: ["erc20"],
  });

  console.log("transfers from me: ", usdcTransfersFromAlbert);
})();
```

This would return all the USDC-related transactions for `thatguyintech.eth` (there's ENS resolution too, which is super nice :D )

```bash
transfers to me:  {
  transfers: [
    {
      blockNum: '0xc59520',
      uniqueId: '0xe1ccb0199953c1e2bdd23a40d272f9c8fab9b29cfe52c832569d8511ef689d5f:log:290',
      hash: '0xe1ccb0199953c1e2bdd23a40d272f9c8fab9b29cfe52c832569d8511ef689d5f',
      from: '0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640',
      to: '0xf5fff32cf83a1a614e15f25ce55b0c0a6b5f8f2c',
      value: 246.311717,
      erc721TokenId: null,
      erc1155Metadata: null,
      tokenId: null,
      asset: 'USDC',
      category: 'erc20',
      rawContract: [Object]
    },
  ...
  ]
}
transfers from me:  {
  transfers: [
    {
      blockNum: '0xd2ad27',
      uniqueId: '0x0da90c9c984f764008b298920ff8d0f1c5cfdabde52af4f6caf0f4c94fdccb0a:log:443',
      hash: '0x0da90c9c984f764008b298920ff8d0f1c5cfdabde52af4f6caf0f4c94fdccb0a',
      from: '0xf5fff32cf83a1a614e15f25ce55b0c0a6b5f8f2c',
      to: '0x93fbe19d6fe3eb7618d9fd4318899c4f51b081c7',
      value: 100,
      erc721TokenId: null,
      erc1155Metadata: null,
      tokenId: null,
      asset: 'USDC',
      category: 'erc20',
      rawContract: [Object]
    },
  ...
  ]
}
```

You can switch across other supported networks by changing the `network` attribute in the `config`.

i.e. with these options:

```js
// from node_modules/alchemy-sdk/dist/src/types/types.d.ts
export declare enum Network {
    ETH_MAINNET = "eth-mainnet",
    ETH_GOERLI = "eth-goerli",
    OPT_MAINNET = "opt-mainnet",
    OPT_GOERLI = "opt-goerli",
    ARB_MAINNET = "arb-mainnet",
    ARB_GOERLI = "arb-goerli",
    MATIC_MAINNET = "polygon-mainnet",
    MATIC_MUMBAI = "polygon-mumbai",
    ASTAR_MAINNET = "astar-mainnet"
}
```

Comment: Flagged thesequestion and answer as they lack the disclosure that it is Alchemy advertisement from Alchemy development relationships manager.

Comment: Thanks for the notice! I edited my answer to share disclosure that I work at Alchemy. I also checked the question you linked as the "original" and noticed that the answers there do not actually solve the problem. Also, I updated the question to be specific about using the alchemy-sdk, for members of the community who are using the alchemy sdk. There are many devs who can benefit from this publicly documented and indexed solution on Ethereum StackExchange 